# Cannot see toolbar in lollipop and higher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

here is my layout code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/pokhara"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#BB000000"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <np.com.audiowalk.audiowalk.helper.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_image"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/ovalbackground"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ktm" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:text="Hem Shrestha"
                    android:textColor="@color/h_white_1000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:text="hereshem@gmail.com"
                    android:textColor="@color/h_white_1000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/edit_account"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="Edit Account" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the output i got
[image: Home Layout]

toolbar appears only in prelollipop device but not working in lollipop.

Comment: which is the root layout?

Comment: once you collapse , by scrolling up it should be showing

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar needs the collapse_mode flag.

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

Pin will say that the toolbar has to be pinned at the top